# Rendering text within a non-rectangular shape

Tags: python, image-processing, text

I am trying to render text on images within non-rectangular (or rectangular at an angle) regions, for example [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOROh.png). I'd like it to render horizontally and fill the available space.

There are various tools I've tried, like PIL and ImageMagick, but these only allow rendering text within rectangular boxes and not arbitrary polygonic regions, which means either some of the space will never be used, or it is possible for text to be rendered outside the intended region.

Ideally I would like to do this entirely in python/using existing python libraries, but I will work in a different language if necessary.

Comment: I do not understand. Do you want the text to be centered in the polygon area? Or do you want the text to be rotated at an angle along one or more sides. You can draw angled text in ImageMagick using -annotate. See https://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/#annotate and https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#annotate

Comment: @fmw42 The text should just be horizontal (and centered, I suppose, though I don't think that should matter too much). Simple translations/rotations aren't an issue. The problem is that if I use a rectangular bounding box (which is what PIL etc. alow you to do), the text would only appear an an area like [this](https://i.imgur.com/gkH3nz4.png). Of course I could choose the area differently, to get more horizontal space, but then I would lose vertical space: I can never efficiently use the whole shape.

Comment: A better example might be puting text in (round/weirdly shaped) textbubbles.

Comment: So correct me if I am wrong, but you want the text to fill as much as it can horizontally and would have uneven length rows. Off the top of my head, I cannot think of any way to do that automatically; but you could do it manually by placing line breaks at appropriate places in the text string so that it wraps to the next line and have it be center aligned. This could be done in ImageMagick with -annotate, for example. But it would mean trial and error to get the line breaks in the right places for the font and font size you use.

Comment: One could write a complicated script that would be given the point size and font and kerning and interword spacing and interline space to get the glyph dimensions so as to compute how many characters are needed for one line at a given vertical location within the limits of the background using a mask to find the edges of the diamond shape. Then write your text one line at a time for the appropriate vertical position of that line within the diamond mask limits.

Comment: You are correct. That is what I want. The text is from user input, so manually adding line breaks won't work.
W.r.t. your second comment, I was afraid it would have to be something like that. Was hoping some library was already out there to do this. If I do manage to come up with something I'm satisfied with I'll add it as an answer to my question.